# Issue when starting MySQL on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, macos

I downloaded Mac OSX MySQL Community edition (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), and when I start it at

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

I meet with the following issue:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Anyone have any good ideas? Thanks in advance.

Meeting with new issues cannot connect to local MySQL instance using MySQL WorkBench, here are my setup and error, looks access denied and anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Website was probably down. It seems back up now, try it.

Comment: @ILikeTau, thanks for the comments, what website do you mean? :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't read. The website you provided, by coincidence, was down when I checked and then came back online. I thought that was your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the service isn't running or it's looking for the socket in the wrong path.

The `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` call you made is actually the client, not the server/service.

There should be a `mysql_safe` executable in that same directory -- try calling that first (you may have to be root).

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Comment: here is the output, any ideas how to proceed next?

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
Password:
150904 22:19:54 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/whenfulllast-lm.err'.
150904 22:19:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data

Comment: That looks like the daemon started fine. Call `usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` again…

Comment: looks successful this time,

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
Password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 338
Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

Comment: One more question, I call "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql" without stop daemon, it that correct? Shall I stop the daemon before I call command "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"? Thanks.

Comment: The daemon needs to run when you call the mysql command. Think of it like `mysql` (the client) connects to `mysqld_safe` (the server). If you stop the daemon, it won't be able to connect.

Comment: thanks a lot and I tried to use MySQL Workbench to connect, but failed. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Please open a new question rather than extend this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88859/discussion-between-mike-g-and-lin-ma).

Comment: here is the new thread we can talk on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409991/mysql-workbench-cannot-connect-to-local-mysql-service-on-mac-osx