# MySQL Workbench cannot connect to local MySQL Service on MAC OSX

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, mysql-workbench

I downloaded Mac OSX MySQL Community edition (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), meeting with new issues cannot connect to local MySQL instance using MySQL WorkBench, here are my setup and error, looks access denied and anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Access denied for user … (using password: YES)" error message is telling you that your user/pass failed to authenticate.

If no user accounts have been configured yet, you will need to log in as the "root" account, which has no password by default.